# Is there a word that encompasses the concepts of cursor, caret, and selection?

Tags: software

In the context of computer software -- you can have a "cursor" for a position between two characters of text, or a "selection" for a region of text.  Is there a word that means "cursor or selection"?  Sort of like a "brother or sister" is a "sibling."

Comment: "Cursor" merely means a position. It's not just for mice and text; databases also have cursors. In this context, I think it's sufficiently obvious we're discussing text cursors only, not mice or other cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of a computer's user interface (display + keyboard + mouse) I would say the current cursor (or *cursors*, since there may be both a mouse and a keyboard cursor), and any currently-highlighted "active" text, are all part of the current [focus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus) (specialised subdivision of sense 5: *centre of attention*).

I'm using Internet Explorer under Windows XP, which shows the addrress of the current webpage at the top of the display. *Control/C* is a keyboard shortcut to copy the currently-highlighted text (ie - that which "has the focus") into the clipboard. But it's easy to get confused about where exactly the *focus* is at any given time, because I can have highlighted text in the address bar *and* the webpage itself simultaneously. *Control/C* copies the text I selected *most recently*, but I can easily forget which one that was, since I may have made that selection some time ago and subsequently been viewing other webpages in other windows, or making a cup of tea.

In short, all software must always know where the **focus** is, otherwise it couldn't meaningfully respond to user input. But only *good* software makes the focus clear to the user at all times.

Comment: Not at all wrong, but it risks being confused with the notion of "focus" in a window management sense. Not surprising, I suppose, at the share a common understanding that *"this is where the input goes"*.

Comment: A window management system just adds another layer, in that only one window can have the focus at any one time.

Comment: "Focus" makes good sense for this, thanks!